# CSS Errors after upgrading to HTTPS

Tags: css, ssl, https

I recently bought a SSL thing to put on my site. Now it looks ugly so I upgraded the files to https://social-build.ml/ not http://social-build.ml/ .

Can anyone explain why this happen? The css files are in the right place

Header code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include "Global.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> 
<head>
<?
// DO NOT TOUCH THE BELOW CODE!
// EVEN IF YOU ARE ADVANCED!
// THIS IS IMPORTANT CODE THAT PREVENTS XSS ATTACKS AND SETS A COOKIE FOR ANALYSIS.
$name = "xss";
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.Travoid.net' );
setcookie('XSSProtection',$name,time() + (86400 * 7)); // 86400 = 1 day
?>

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<title>Travoid</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//social-build.ml/Base/Style/Main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//social-build.ml/Base/Style/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.tumuski.com/library/Nibbler/Nibbler.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js"></script>
<script>WebFont.load({
  google: {
    families: ["Source Sans Pro:200,300,regular,600,700,900"]
  }
});</script>

<style>

h1 {
font-weight: 300;
}
font {
font-weight: 400;
}

</style>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.redirect').click(function(){
        window.location = $(this).attr('redirect');
        });
        });
        </script>



    </head>
    <body>

        <div align='center'>

        </div>



    <?php
// Show premium background if premium
if ($myU->Premium == 1) {
    echo "
    <style>
    body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
color: #333;
background-color: black;
background-image: url('https://social-build.ml/images/dark-striped-pattern-1780.png');
line-height: 20px;
font-weight: 400;
height:100%;
}
</style>
";
}
if (!$User) {
    echo "
    <style>
    body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
color: #333;
line-height: 20px;
font-weight: 400;
height:100%;
}
</style>
    ";
}
if ($myU->Premium == 0) {
        echo "
    <style>
    body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
color: #333;
line-height: 20px;
font-weight: 400;
height:100%;
}
</style>
    ";
}

// Show different headers if user is premium/not premium    
if ($myU->Premium == 0) {
echo "

<div id='navbar_links'>

";
}
else {
echo "
<div id='navbar_links_premium'>

";
}
?>


                <!--
                Center the navbar
                -->

                <center>


                <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='1005'>
                    <tr>
                        <td width='200'>
<div id='logo1'>
                            <a href='https://social-build.ml/index.php'><font size='5'><font style='line-height:40px; font-weight: 300;'>Travoid</font></font></a></div>
                        </td>
                        <td>

                            <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
                                <tr>

                                    <td>
                                        <a href='https://social-build.ml/index.php'>Home</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href='https://social-build.ml/Blog/'>Blog</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href='https://social-build.ml/users/'>Members</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href='https://social-build.ml/Store/Store.php'>Marketplace</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href='https://social-build.ml/Store/UserStore.php'>Catalog</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href='https://social-build.ml/Groups/'>Groups</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href='https://social-build.ml/Forum/'>Forums</a>


                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                    <a href='https://social-build.ml/Memberships/UpgradeAccount.php'>Upgrade</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                    <a href='https://social-build.ml/Games/index.html'>Games</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <?php


                                        if ($User) {

                                    //  echo "
                                    //<td>
                                    //  <a href='https://social-build.ml/Trade/'>Trade</a>
                                //  </td>
                                //      ";

                                        }

                                    ?>
                                    <?php

                                        if ($myU->PowerAdmin == "true") {

                                            echo "
                                    <td>
                                        <a href='https://social-build.ml/Admin/?tab=configuration'>Admin</a>
                                    </td>
                                            ";

                                        }



                                    if ($User) {

                                        echo "
                                    <td style='padding-left:35px;'>
                                        <a href='https://social-build.ml/user.php?ID=$myU->ID'>$User</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>

<a href='https://social-build.ml/Memberships/PurchaseBux.php'><font color='FFA500' title='$myU->Bux'>$Bux Crowns</a>                </font>                     </a>


                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href='https://social-build.ml/Logout.php'>Logout</a>
                                    </td>
                                        ";

                                    }
                                    else {

                                        echo "
                                    <td style='padding-left:35px;'>
                                        <a href='https://social-build.ml/Login.php'>Login</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href='https://social-build.ml/register.php'>Register</a>
                                    </td>
                                        ";

                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </center>
            </div>

        <?php
        // WHEN UPDATING THE SUBBAR LINKS, EDIT BOTH BELOW.
        // UPDATE $myU->Premium == 0 AND $myU->Premium == 1
        // IF YOU ARE CONFUSED, <DON'T> EDIT IT!
        // -JOE
        ?>

    <?php  if ($User) { 
if ($myU->Premium == 0) {
    echo "<center>
        <div id='navbar_links2'>
        <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href='https://social-build.ml//account.php'>Account</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href='https://social-build.ml/user.php?ID=$myU->ID'>Public Profile</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href='https://social-build.ml//character.php'>Character</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href='https://social-build.ml/FriendRequests.php'>Friend Requests ($FriendsPending)</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href='https://social-build.ml/inbox.php'>Inbox ($PMs)</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href='https://social-build.ml/ItemLogs.php?view=all'>Purchase Logs</a>
                </td>


            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        </center>
        ";
}
if ($myU->Premium == 1) {
    echo "<center>
        <div id='navbar_links2' style='background-color:#333333; color:blue;'>
        <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href='https://social-build.ml//account.php'>Account</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href='https://social-build.ml/user.php?ID=$myU->ID'>Public Profile</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href='https://social-build.ml//character.php'>Character</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href='https://social-build.ml/FriendRequests.php'>Friend Requests ($FriendsPending)</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href='https://social-build.ml/inbox.php'>Inbox ($PMs)</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href='https://social-build.ml/Ads/index.php'>Advertisements</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href='https://social-build.ml/ItemLogs.php?view=all'>Purchase Logs</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href='https://social-build.ml/Trade/'>Trade Requests ($Trades)</a>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        </center>
        ";
}
    }
        ?>
    <center>


            <!--End Top Bar-->

            <!--Important notification, use for emergencies -->

            <!-- 
            <div class='bannernotification' style='font-weight: 400; background-color: #00a2ff; box-shadow: 0px 0px; 0px; 0px;'>
            <div class='bannernotificationtext'> You will be logged out of your account in <b>1 minute</b>. Your data will not be lost. This is part of a website safety inspection. </div></div> <br /><br />
            -->


            <?php
            if ($myU->Verified == "0") {
            echo "
            <div id='error'>
<font size='3'><center>You haven't verified your account yet! Click <a href='https://social-build.ml/EmailSend.php?email=$myU->Email'>here</a> to verify.</font></div></center>

";
}
?>


            <?php 

            if ($myU->Premium == 0 AND $User) {
            if (!empty($gB->Text)) { echo "






            <style>
            .bannernotification {
padding: 10px 5px;
background-color: #00a2ff;
box-shadow: gray 0px 1px 3px 0px;
}
.bannernotificationtext {
color: white;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
font-size:16px;
text-align: center;
}
</style>


        <div class='bannernotification' style='font-weight: 400; box-shadow: 0px 0px; 0px; 0px;'>
<div class='bannernotificationtext'> ".nl2br($gB->Text)." </div></div>
";






                $kkk = 30*6;
                $extratime = 86400*$kkk;
                $premiumtime = time() + $extratime;
                //echo $premiumtime;
                echo "
            </div>

            </center>

            ";
            }
            }
            if ($myU->Premium == 1) {
            if (!empty($gB->Text)) { echo "






            <style>
            .bannernotification {
padding: 10px 5px;
background-color: #ffa550;
box-shadow: gray 0px 1px 3px 0px;
}
.bannernotificationtext {
color: white;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
font-size:16px;
text-align: center;
}
</style>


        <div class='bannernotification' style='font-weight: 400; background-color:gray; box-shadow: 0px 0px; 0px; 0px;'>
<div class='bannernotificationtext'> ".nl2br($gB->Text)." </div></div>
";






                $kkk = 30*6;
                $extratime = 86400*$kkk;
                $premiumtime = time() + $extratime;
                //echo $premiumtime;
                echo "
            </div>

            </center>

            ";
            }
            }

            elseif (!$User) {
                if (!empty($gB->Text)) { echo "






            <style>
            .bannernotification {
padding: 10px 5px;
background-color: #00a2ff;
box-shadow: gray 0px 1px 3px 0px;
}
.bannernotificationtext {
color: white;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
font-size:16px;
text-align: center;
}
</style>


        <div class='bannernotification' style='font-weight: 400; box-shadow: 0px 0px; 0px; 0px;'>
<div class='bannernotificationtext'> ".nl2br($gB->Text)." </div></div>
";






                $kkk = 30*6;
                $extratime = 86400*$kkk;
                $premiumtime = time() + $extratime;
                //echo $premiumtime;
                echo "
            </div>

            </center>

            ";
            }
            }



            echo "<br />";




$getAllGroups = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Groups");

    while ($gAG = mysql_fetch_object($getAllGroups)) {

        $getAllMembers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM GroupMembers WHERE GroupID='$gAG->ID'");
        $gA = mysql_num_rows($getAllMembers);

        mysql_query("UPDATE Groups SET GroupMembers='$gA' WHERE ID='$gAG->ID'");

    }

?>
<?php
if ($myU->PowerAdmin == "true"||$myU->PowerMegaModerator == "true"||$myU->PowerImageModerator == "true") {
$NumOnline = mysql_num_rows($NumOnline = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE $now < expireTime"));
if ($NumR > 0) {

    $SayP = "<font color='red'><b>Unmoderated Profanity Reports ($NumR)</b></font>";

}
else {

    $SayP = "Unmoderated Profanity Reports ($NumR)";

}

if ($NumPending > 0) {

    $SayNP = "<font color='red'><b>Unmoderated User Items ($NumPending)</b></font>";

}
else {

    $SayNP = "Unmoderated User Items ($NumPending)";

}
if ($myU->PowerAdmin == "true"||$myU->PowerMegaModerator == "true") {
$NumWaiting = mysql_num_rows($NumWaiting = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ItemDrafts"));
if ($NumWaiting > 0) {

    $SayNW = "<font color='red'><b>Unmoderated Store Items ($NumWaiting)</b></font>";

}
else {

    $SayNW = "Unmoderated Store Items ($NumWaiting)";

}
}
$getPending1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM GroupsPending ORDER BY ID");
$NumPending1 = mysql_num_rows($getPending1);
$getPending2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM GroupsLogo");
$NumPending2 = mysql_num_rows($getPending2);


if ($NumPending1 > 0) {

    $SayNP1 = "<font color='red'><b><a href='../ModerateGroups.php'>Unmoderated Groups ($NumPending1)</a></b></font>";

}
else {

    $SayNP1 = "<a href='../ModerateGroups.php'>Unmoderated Groups ($NumPending1)</a>";

}

if ($NumPending2 > 0) {

    $SayNP2 = "<font color='red'><b><a href='../ModerateLogos.php'>Unmoderated Group Logos ($NumPending2)</a></b></font>";

}

else {

    $SayNP2 = "<a href='../ModerateLogos.php'>Unmoderated Group Logos ($NumPending2)</a>";

}

if ($NumPending3 > 0) {

    $SayNP3 = "<font color='red'><b><a href='../PendingAds.php'>Unmoderated Ads ($NumPending3)</a></b></font>";

}

else {

    $SayNP3 = "<a href='../PendingAds.php'>Unmoderated Ads ($NumPending3)</a>";

}












if ($myU->PowerAdmin == "true"||$myU->PowerMegaModerator == "true") {
$AllShow = $NumR + $NumPending + $NumWaiting + $NumPending1 + $NumPending2 + $NumPending3;
}
else {
$AllShow = $NumR + $NumPending + $NumWaiting + $NumPending1 + $NumPending2 + $NumPending3;
}
if ($NumPending > 0||$NumR > 0||$NumWaiting > 0||$NumPending1 > 0||$NumPending2 > 0||$NumPending3 > 0) {
$KShow = "<font color='red'><b>Show Quick Admin <b>&uarr; ($AllShow)</b></font>";
}
else {
$KShow = "Show Quick Admin <b>&uarr; ($AllShow)";
}


echo "
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#quickAdmin_hide').hide();
    $('#quick_admin').hide();
        $('#quickAdmin_show').click(function(){
        $('#quick_admin').delay(1).slideDown();
        $('#quickAdmin_hide').delay(1).slideDown();
        $('#quickAdmin_show').slideUp();
        });
        $('#quickAdmin_hide').click(function(){
        $('#quick_admin').delay(1).slideUp();
        $('#quickAdmin_hide').slideUp();
        $('#quickAdmin_show').delay(1).slideDown();
        });
  });
</script>
";
echo "
<div id='quickAdmin_show' style='position:fixed;bottom:0px;right:250px;background:#eee;padding:5px;border:1px solid #aaa; cursor:pointer; font-size:9pt;'>
$KShow</b>
</div>
<div id='quickAdmin_hide' style='position:fixed;bottom:110px;right:250px;background:#eee;padding:5px;border:1px solid #aaa;cursor:pointer; font-size:9pt;'>
Hide Quick Admin <b>&darr;</b><br /><br /><br /><br />
</div>
<div id='quick_admin' style='position:fixed;bottom:0px;right:250px;background:#eee;padding:5px;border:1px solid #aaa; font-size:9pt;'>
<div align='left'>
";


if ($myU->PowerAdmin == "true"||$myU->PowerMegaModerator == "true") {
echo "
<a href='../Reports.php'>$SayP</a>
<br />
";
}
if ($myU->PowerAdmin == "true"||$myU->PowerMegaModerator == "true"||$myU->PowerImageModerator == "true") {
echo "<a href='../ItemModeration.php'>$SayNP</a>
<br />
";
}
if ($myU->PowerAdmin == "true"||$myU->PowerMegaModerator == "true") {
echo "<a href='../ItemRelease.php'>$SayNW</a><br />";
}
if ($myU->PowerAdmin == "true"||$myU->PowerMegaModerator == "true") {
if ($NumPending4 > 0) {

    $SayNP4 = "<font color='red'><b><a href='../RunningAds.php'>Running Ads ($NumPending4)</a></b></font>";

}

else {

    $SayNP4 = "<font color='red'><a href='../RunningAds.php'>Running Ads ($NumPending4)</a></font>";

}



echo "
$SayNP1
<br />
$SayNP2
<br />
$SayNP3
<br />
$SayNP4
<br />
<a href='../online.php'><b>Online Users (".$NumOnline.") </b></a>
<br />
</div>
";
}
}
echo "</div></div>";


















if($myU)
{
?>
<div pub-key="pub-f144de56-028d-43a9-aaa6-1880aa4b7f1d" sub-key="sub-b3038e9e-d36a-11e1-b1c8-9bc3b49a6845" ssl="off" origin="pubsub.pubnub.com" id="pubnub"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub-3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>(function(){

 // LISTEN FOR MESSAGES
 PUBNUB.subscribe({
 channel : "my_channel", // CONNECT TO THIS CHANNEL.

 restore : true, // STAY CONNECTED, EVEN WHEN BROWSER IS CLOSED
 // OR WHEN PAGE CHANGES.

 callback : function(message) { // RECEIVED A MESSAGE.
        var myid2 = document.getElementById("currentchatid").style.top;
        var mychatid = mychatid2.substr(0,6);
        var otheruserchat = document.getElementById('otheruserchat').value;
        if(message.substr(0,10) == 'chatinvite')
        {
        if(message.substr(11,5) == '<?echo$myU->ingamenum;?>')
        {
        }
        else
        {
        if(message.substr(17,5) == '<?echo$myU->ingamenum;?>')
        {
        var inviteusernum = message.substr(11,5);
        $('#chat_output').load('/Header.php?chataction=getchat&usertocheckchat=ddd&new=1');
        }
        else
        {
        }
        }
        }
        if(message.substr(0,11) == 'chatmessage')
        {
        if(message.substr(12,6) == mychatid)
        {
        var message2 = message.replace(/00dz00/g,"&nbsp");
        var message3 = message2.replace("<?echo$myU->Username;?>","<font color='blue'><?echo$myU->Username;?></font><br /><br />");
        var message4 = message3.replace(otheruserchat,"<font color='orange'>"+otheruserchat+"</font><br /><br />");
        mychatmessages.innerHTML = (mychatmessages.innerHTML+'<div style="float:left;word-wrap:break-word;   word-spacing: 30000px; 
">'+message3.substr(500)+'</div><br /><br />')
        }
        else
        {
        }
        }
        if(message.substr(0,10) == 'chatremove')
        {
        if(message.substr(17,5) == '<?echo$myU->ingamenum;?>')
        {
        $('#chat_output').load('/Header.php?chataction=remove&removenew=1');
        }
        else
        {
        }
        }
 },

 connect : function() { // CONNECTION ESTABLISHED.

 }
 })

})();</script>
<?
echo "
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function(){
    if(mychatid > 0)
    {
    $('#chat_interface').hide().delay(2000).show();
    }
    if(mychatid < 1)
    {
 $('#chat_interface').hide();
    }
        $('#show_chat').click(function(){
     $('#chat_interface').delay(500).fadeIn(500);
            });
        $('#close_chat').click(function(){
     $('#chat_interface').delay(500).slideUp();
        $('#close_chat').slideUp();
        $('#show_chat').delay(1000).slideDown();
        });
 });
</script>
";
echo "
<div id='show_chat' style='position:fixed;bottom:1px;right:5px;width:150px;border:2px solid #aaa;border-radius:5px; cursor:hand;background:#F0F0F0;'>
<center>Open Chat</center>
</div>
<div id='close_chat' style='width:225px;position:fixed;bottom:150px;right:5px;border:2px solid #aaa;border-radius:5px; cursor:hand;background:#F0F0F0; cursor:hand;'>
<center>Close Chat <b>&darr;</b></center>
</div>
<div id='chat_interface' style='height:140px;width:225px;position:fixed;bottom:0px;right:5px;border:2px solid #aaa;border-radius:5px;background:#F0F0F0;'>
<br />
<div id='chatmessage_thing'><center><b>Invite a user to chat.</b></center></div>
<br />
<center>
<input type='text' id='cleartext_chat' name='username_chat' style='border:1px solid grey; color:grey; font-weight:bold;' value='Type username here'>
<button name='invite_chat' id='invitechat_button' value='' onclick='invitechat(this.value)' style='cursor:hand;'>Invite</button>
<br /><br />
<b><div id='chat_output'></div></b>
</center>
";
echo "</div>";
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#cleartext_chat').val('').delay().val('Type username here');
 });
 $('#cleartext_chat').click(function(){
 $('#cleartext_chat').val('');
    $('#invitechat_button').val('');
 });
 <?
 if($myU->chatid > 0)
 {
 ?>
 var mychatid = <?echo$myU->chatid;?>;
 if(mychatid > 0)
 {
 $('#chat_output').load('/Header.php?chataction=getchat&usertocheckchat=ddd&new=1');
        $('#close_chat').hide();
        $('#show_chat').hide();
        $('#close_chat2').show();
 }
 <?
 }
 ?>
function invitechat()
{
var usernamea = $('#cleartext_chat').val();
var username = usernamea.toLowerCase();
var my_usernamea = '<?echo$myU->Username;?>';
var my_username = my_usernamea.toLowerCase();
if(username.length < 1)
{
$('#chat_output').html('Please type in a username.');
}
if(username == my_username)
{
$('#chat_output').html('You cannot invite yourself!');
}
if(username != my_username && username.length > 0)
{
$('#chat_output').load('/Header.php?chataction=getchat&usertocheckchat='+username);
}
}
function removechat()
{
$('#chat_output').load('/Header.php?chataction=removechat');
}
</script>
<script>
$('#close_chat').hide();
$('#chat_interface').hide();
$('#show_chat').click(function(){
var mychatid5 = document.getElementById("currentchatid").style.top;
$('#show_chat').slideUp(500);
$('#chat_interface').delay(500).slideDown(500);
if(mychatid5 < 1)
{
$('#close_chat').delay(1000).slideDown(500);
}
if(mychatid5 > 0)
{
$('#close_chat2').delay(1000).slideDown(500);
}
});
$('#close_chat').click(function(){
$('#close_chat').slideUp(500);
$('#chat_interface').delay(500).slideUp(500);
$('#show_chat').delay(1000).slideDown(500);
});
$('#close_chat2').click(function(){
var mychatid5 = document.getElementById("currentchatid").style.top;
$('#close_chat2').slideUp(500);
$('#chat_interface').delay(500).slideUp(500);
$('#show_chat').delay(1000).slideDown(500);
});
</script>
<div id='currentchatid'></div>
<input type='hidden' id='otheruserchat'>
<?
}
?>
            <!--End Announcement Bar-->


        <?php
            $connection = mysql_pconnect("sql212.epizy.com","epiz_20432576","0WaQxsHv") or die("Error connecting to database, hang tight, we are working on it.");
            mysql_select_db("epiz_20432576_db") or die("Error connecting to database, hang tight, we are working on it...");
            $getAds = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Ads WHERE Active='1' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
            $gU = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID");

            while ($gA = @mysql_Fetch_object($getAds)) {

            $Timer = time();

            if ($Timer >= $gA->Time) {
            mysql_query("UPDATE Ads SET Active=0 WHERE AdID='$gA->AdID'");
            }
            $hashedad = hash('ripemd160',"".$gA->Name."");
            echo "<center>
            <a href='$gA->Link' target='_BLANK'>
            <img src='$gA->Image' height='90' width='728'></img>
            </a>
            <table width='720px'>
            <tr>
            <td width='40%'></td>
            <td width='50%' style='font-weight:400;'>Ad by $gA->Username</td>
            </tr>
            </table>

            </center><br /><br />";

            }
        ?>

            <!--Begin Main Container-->

                <center>
                    <div id="Container"><div align='left'>
                <?php 

                    $rainbow = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID='".$myU->ID."'");
                    $rainbow = mysql_fetch_object($rainbow);

                    $_SESSION['Username'] = $rainbow->Username;
                    $_SESSION['Password'] = $rainbow->Password;


                ?>
```

Comment: Show code please...

Comment: Of what? Where it links to the css?

Comment: Yes, please. :)

Comment: Here is the header part where it links all of the pages with the css:

Comment: <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<title>Travoid</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://social-build.ml/Base/Style/Main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://social-build.ml/Base/Style/Bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.tumuski.com/library/Nibbler/Nibbler.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js">

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="social-build.ml/Base/Style/Bootstrap.css"> should be <link rel="stylesheet" href="//social-build.ml/Base/Style/Bootstrap.css"> add // instead of http or https in all your external linkings

Comment: see my answer below and accept when it fixes. :)

Answer (score 1):

When using https, you have to include all your assets (css, images, js...) using the same protocol. So, form example, you need to change this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://social-build.ml/Base/Style/Main.css">
```

to this (using https prefix):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://social-build.ml/Base/Style/Main.css">
```

or even better, using the generic indicator

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//social-build.ml/Base/Style/Main.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the path to css file from http://.... to https://
Look at the errors in browser debugger

Comment: If you look at the page's source code, you can see the style links start with http://. You have to configure your stylesheets linking from https

Answer (score 0):

Change your css path from **http** to **https** like below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://social-build.ml/Base/Style/Main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://social-build.ml/Base/Style/Bootstrap.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://social-build.ml/Base/Style/Main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://social-build.ml/Base/Style/Bootstrap.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your external linkings to make sure the browser uses what ever protocol it is currently using by adding `//` instead of where http:// or https:// is.

For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="social-build.ml/Base/Style/Bootstrap.css">
```

Would be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//social-build.ml/Base/Style/Bootstrap.css">
```

Comment: Okay i used it and some buttons have changed but not the whole header part.

Comment: Ok. You do not need to change any buttons to this. Only the stuff in the header. Are you able to edit the header content?

Comment: Yes. Here ill put all of the content in a pastebin. https://pastebin.com/raw/Y8iXi0Rs

Comment: Update your original answer. ?

Comment: Okay i have added it on the main post